# Correct English term to indicate "the culture one is born in"?

Tags: terminology

What is the English term that one uses to indicate "the culture one is born in"?

Comment: The *nation* one is born in is one's *nationality*. The culture? Not sure. One's *native culture*, I suppose.

Comment: E.g. "I'm from Japan, but I have lived in the US since I was two years old."? I suppose then you were born in a Japanese culture but you then assimilated the values and customs of the US. I think you need to add more context, your question is not very clear to me.

Comment: _Native culture_ or _birth culture_ (the latter only if there is a later culture to refer to).

Comment: @Mari-LouA As per that example, for you, English is a (adopted/acquired/second/native?) language?

Answer (score 2):

The word 'native' is used to describe anything that applies to you at the time of your birth. So the culture you were born in would be your '**native culture**'.

People sometimes use 'native' to mean 'the main thing' (as in "<strike>since I came to England, English has become my native language</strike>") but this is wrong.

Comment: But what if you're German born, but adopted and raised in England since age 1? Wouldn't English be more native to you?

Comment: No, that's my point. Strictly German is your native culture.

Answer (score 2):

[This blog entry](https://beyondtwoworlds.com/tag/birth-culture/) has “**birth culture**” as its title and then once again near the end to describe the culture of the author’s birth.  “**Cultural roots**” is also used with that meaning near the article's top.
(from *Beyond Two Worlds: Musings of a Taiwanese-American Adoptee*)

As long as it’s clear that you’re talking/writing about some **person’s** “native culture” then there would be little chance for ambiguity, but “native culture/s” can also mean [a country’s] “indigenous culture/s,” i.e., the culture of its indigenous/native inhabitants.  (Just as, to be fair, “birth culture” should be used with an appropriate personal possessive pronoun to avoid confusion with other meanings of that term, so maybe "cultural roots" would be less prone to confusion)

Answer (score 2):

Heritage-

a heritage of poverty and suffering; a national heritage of honor, pride, andcourage.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you're looking for, but how about '[milieu](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/milieu)':

> A person’s social environment:
>
> he grew up in a military milieu

Another [definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/milieu)

> surroundings, especially of a social or cultural nature